# How to interpolate a function return of column names into the SELECT section of a QUERY [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, query, schema, functions

I deal with tables with many columns - recently I realised I can generate a list of column names excluding one column (maybe PK), that I don't want.

Like so:

```
mysql> SET @notColumns = 'primary_key,another_column';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'our_dev' AND TABLE_NAME = 'subscriptions' AND FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME, @notColumns) = 0  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| lots,of,columns,excluding,those,specified,comma,separated,in,the,varchar,variable |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want to make this into a function with 2 parameters, table name and a string of comma-separated values, but I couldn't get the table parameter to work, so with a fixed table name:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION notColumns(notColumns VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) 
RETURN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'our_db' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'subscriptions' 
AND FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME, @notColumns) = 0  
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME);
```

This outputs what I want, but if I try and interpolate with it, like so:

```
SELECT (SELECT notColumns('primary_key,other_column)) FROM subscriptions;
```

I just get the column names again, instead of the corresponding values from the 1st record in the table that I want
`lots,of,columns,excluding,those,specified,comma,separated,in,the,varchar,variable`

Is this column interpolation even possible? If so what can I do to make the SQL query language read the output of my function as raw text?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need dynamic sql

like so

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION notColumns(notColumns VARCHAR(255)) 
> RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) 
> RETURN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'our_db' 
> AND TABLE_NAME = 'subscriptions' 
> AND FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME, @notColumns) = 0  
> GROUP BY TABLE_NAME);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT notColumns("primary_key,other_column")
> ```
>
> ```
> | notColumns("primary_key,other_column") |
> | :------------------------------------- |
> | null                                   |
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',notColumns("primary_key,other_column"),' FROM subscriptions;');
> SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | @sql |
> | :--- |
> | null |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bf5f6faae386b833a6e1551a5e13582)*